# Date Format Changes Due To Custom Bibstrings

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I have added custom bibstrings and used language `ngerman`. If I leave the definition of `ngerman` before bibstrings blank, it will print the date format as desired. DD.MM.YYYY

However, if I use LanguageMapping `ngerman` or `german`, it will show up as DD/MM/YYYY - why is that and what's the correct way to display the correct format?

LBX file:

```
\ProvidesFile{custombibstrings.lbx}[2019 SoSe]
\DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
  inherit      = {ngerman},
  andothers    = {{et al\adddot}{et al\adddot}},
  byeditor     = {{herausgegeben von}{hg\adddotspace von}},
  bytranslator = {{übersetzt von} {{\"u}bers\adddotspace von}},
  editor       = {{Herausgeber}{Hg\adddot}},
  editors      = {{Herausgeber}{Hg\adddot}},
  urlseen      = {{letzter Abruf}{letzter Abruf}},
  paragraph    = {{Paragraph}{\S}},
  subparagraph = {{Absatz}{Abs\adddot}},
  article      = {{Artikel}{Art\adddot}},
  bydirector   = {{unter der Regie von}{unter der Regie von}},
  byproducer   = {{produziert von}{produziert von}},
  volume       = {{Vol\adddot}{Vol\adddot}},
  seriesseason = {{Staffel}{Staffel}},
  episode      = {{Episode}{Episode}},
  duration     = {{Spieldauer}{Spieldauer}},
  fsk          = {{FSK}{FSK}},
}
```

MWE

```
% arara: lualatex: { shell: true, synctex: true }
% arara: biber
% arara: lualatex: { shell: true, synctex: true }
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@online{Amano.2011,
 author = {Amano, Fumiko},
 title = {Testimonial Videos of Survivors},
 url = {https://www.global-peace.go.jp/OTHER/ot_german_pic_syousai.php?gbID=920&dt=161012173049},
 date = {2011-11-18},
 urldate = {2019-08-23},
 maintitle = {National Peace Memorial Halls for the Atomic Bomb Victims in Hiroshima and Nagasaki},
 organization = {{Net-Gtas Global Network}},
 keywords = {primary}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  a4paper,
  headings=standardclasses,
  listof=totoc,
  numbers=noenddot
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=2.50cm, bottom=2.00cm, footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[main=ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[ngerman]{isodate}
\usepackage[ngerman]{datetime}

\usepackage[match,MogaHMinEx90]{luatexja-preset}
\setmainjfont{MogaHMinEx90}
\usepackage{luatexja-ruby}
\ltjsetparameter{jacharrange={-3}} %    punctuation is Latin

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear,
  sorting=nyvt,
  datamodel=customstyles,
  maxnames=25,
  innamebeforetitle=true,
  usetranslator=true,
  alldates=terse,
  labeldate=year,
  dashed=false,
  isbn=false
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage[hidelinks, pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}
\begin{filecontents}{customstyles.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{video}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{
  duration,
  format,
  type,
}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=list,datatype=name]{
  director,
  producer,
}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field, datatype=verbatim]{
  fsk,
  seriesseason,
  episode,
}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[video]{
  duration,
  director,
  episode,
  format,
  fsk,
  producer,
  seriesseason,
  type,
}
\end{filecontents}
% regarded in custombibstrings
\NewBibliographyString{bydirector,duration,episode,format,fsk,paragraph,subparagraph,article,byproducer,seriesseason}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{german}{custombibstrings}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite=false]{
      \pertype{article}
      \step[fieldsource=entrysubtype, match=\regexp{\Anewspaper\Z}, final]
      \step[fieldsource=journal, final]
      \step[fieldset=author, origfieldval, final]
      \step[fieldsource=author, match=\regexp{\A(.*)\Z}, replace=\regexp{\{$1\}}]
      \step[fieldset=author+an, fieldvalue={1=journalauthor}]
      \step[fieldset=options, fieldvalue={journalauthor}]
    }
  }
}

% smallcaps
\newtoggle{bbx@journalauthor}
\DeclareEntryOption[boolean]{journalauthor}[true]{%
\settoggle{bbx@journalauthor}{#1}}

\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{%
  \ifitemannotation{journalauthor}
    {\mkbibemph{#1}}
    {\textsc{#1}}}

\newtoggle{bbx@director}
\DeclareEntryOption[boolean]{director}[true]{%
\settoggle{bbx@director}{#1}}

\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{%
  \ifitemannotation{director}
    {\mkbibemph{#1}}
    {\textsc{#1}}}

\newtoggle{bbx@producer}
\DeclareEntryOption[boolean]{producer}[true]{%
\settoggle{bbx@producer}{#1}}

\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{%
  \ifitemannotation{producer}
    {\mkbibemph{#1}}
    {\textsc{#1}}}    

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}

% editor in parentheses
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace} 
\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}
\DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,online]
  {title}{#1\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{\mkbibemph{#1}\isdot} % thesis title italic

% no period after addon titles
\renewcommand*{\titleaddonpunct}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{titleaddon}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\DeclareFieldAlias{booktitleaddon}{titleaddon}
\DeclareFieldAlias{maintitleaddon}{titleaddon}
\DeclareFieldAlias{journaltitleaddon}{titleaddon}
\DeclareFieldAlias{lawtitleaddon}{titleaddon}
\DeclareFieldAlias{subtitleaddon}{titleaddon}

\newbibmacro{online:editor+maintitle}{% organization in front of maintitle
  \printlist{organization}%
  \clearlist{organization}%
  \setunit*{\addcolon\space}%
  \printnames{editor}%
  \setunit*{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{maintitle}}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{online}
  {\usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {\usebibmacro{online:editor+maintitle}}
  {}{}
\xpatchbibmacro{editorstrg}{\bibstring}{\bibcpstring}{}{}
\xpatchbibmacro{editorstrg}{\bibstring}{\bibcpstring}{}{}

\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx@journalauthor}
    {}
    {\printtext{%
     \bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\DeclareNameAlias{ineditor}{sortname}

\renewcommand*{\volnumdelim}{\addcomma\space}

% set online sources as per IOA
\renewbibmacro*{addendum+pubstate}{%
  \setunit{\space}%
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{pubstate}}

 \DeclareListFormat[online,law]{organization}{% organization in caps 
  \textsc{%
    \usebibmacro{list:delim}{#1}%
    #1\isdot
    \usebibmacro{list:andothers}}} 

\urlstyle{same}% 
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibparens{\bibstring{urlseen}\addcolon\space#1}}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CITING
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\makeatletter 
\renewbibmacro*{cite:labeldate+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[extblx@inner\blx@delimcontext delims]{%
       \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
         \iftoggle{bbx@journalauthor}
           {\printfield{issue}%
            \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
            \printtext[\blx@delimcontext labeldate]{%
              \printdateextra}}
           {\printtext[\blx@delimcontext labeldate]{%
              \printlabeldateextra}}}}}}
\makeatother

\renewcommand\postnotedelim{\addcolon\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MAIN
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\nocite{*} 
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={Literaturverzeichnis}]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you mean with *f I leave the definition of ngerman before bibstrings blank*, please? Also the code is quite long (I know why), would it be possible to remove some of it while still showing the problem? Certainly `luatexja-preset` is not needed for the MWE (and I hope that you can also get rid of some of the `biblatex` code...)

Comment: Note also that the MWE does *not* produce `custombibstrings.lbx`, so when  run in an empty folder it will produce the warning `File 'custombibstrings.lbx' not found! Ignoring mapping 'german' -> 'custombibstrings'.`and the custom bibstrings will not be defined as expected.

Comment: oh sorry sure - \DeclareLanguageMapping{german}{custombibstrings} if I turn that into \DeclareLanguageMapping{}{custombibstrings} it works (also added the lbx file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `.lbx` files should always contain definitions for at least two things.

1. The bibliography **strings** (with `\DeclareBibliographyStrings`)
2. and the bibliography **extras** (mostly date handling, format for ordinals, etc. with `\DeclareBibliographyExtras`).

The `.lbx` file is currently missing a definition for the bibliography extras. My `biblatex` even complains about this in the `.log`

> ```
> Package biblatex Warning: Using fallback definition for \mkbibdateshort.
> (biblatex)                The command should be defined in the .lbx file.
> (biblatex)                If you see this message, the .lbx file could not be
> (biblatex)                loaded, is faulty or does not contain a definition
> (biblatex)                for \mkbibdateshort.
>
>
> Package biblatex Warning: Using fallback definition for \mkbibdateshort.
> (biblatex)                The command should be defined in the .lbx file.
> (biblatex)                If you see this message, the .lbx file could not be
> (biblatex)                loaded, is faulty or does not contain a definition
> (biblatex)                for \mkbibdateshort.
> ```

---

Since you essentially write a new `.lbx` file, you'll need to inherit the bibliography extras from another language or define all necessary commands from scratch. In your case inheriting from `ngerman` with `\InheritBibliographyExtras{ngerman}` seems the best option. You can still overwrite the definitions with a `\DeclareBibliographyExtras`.

The situation is similar with the bibliography strings, but there the inheritance is provided by the special key-value-pair `inherit = {ngerman},` in `\DeclareBibliographyStrings`.

I strongly suggest you do yourself a favour and add the language name to the generic filename `custombibstrings.lbx` to make it read `custombibstrings-ngerman.lbx` (of course if you can come up with a more descriptive name than `custombibstrings` that might also be useful...)

```
\ProvidesFile{custombibstrings-ngerman.lbx}[2019 SoSe]

\InheritBibliographyExtras{ngerman}

\DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
  inherit      = {ngerman},
  andothers    = {{et al\adddot}{et al\adddot}},
  byeditor     = {{herausgegeben von}{hg\adddotspace von}},
  bytranslator = {{übersetzt von} {übers\adddotspace von}},
  editor       = {{Herausgeber}{Hg\adddot}},
  editors      = {{Herausgeber}{Hg\adddot}},
  urlseen      = {{letzter Abruf}{letzter Abruf}},
  paragraph    = {{Paragraph}{\S}},
  subparagraph = {{Absatz}{Abs\adddot}},
  article      = {{Artikel}{Art\adddot}},
  bydirector   = {{unter der Regie von}{unter der Regie von}},
  byproducer   = {{produziert von}{produziert von}},
  volume       = {{Vol\adddot}{Vol\adddot}},
  seriesseason = {{Staffel}{Staffel}},
  episode      = {{Episode}{Episode}},
  duration     = {{Spieldauer}{Spieldauer}},
  fsk          = {{FSK}{FSK}},
}
```

Naturally you'll then need

```
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{custombibstrings-ngerman}
```

With this file and this one line changed the MWE produces

[image: Amano, Fumiko (18.11.2011): Testimonial Videos of Survivors. Net-Gtas Global Network: National Peace Memorial Halls for the Atomic Bomb Victims in Hiroshima and Nagasaki. https://www.global-peace.go.jp/OTHER/ot german pic syousai.php?gbID=920&dt=161012173049 (letzter Abruf: 23.08.2019).]

*edit* Changed `{\"u}bers\adddotspace von` to `übers\adddotspace von`.

Comment: thank you very much! wasn't aware of it. :)